# Stopping e-calendar-factory and e-addressbook-factory

Tags: 12.04, evolution, process

How can I prevent e-calendar-factory and e-addressbook-factory from ever starting? If I manually kill the processes they just start up again? Between the two they are spamming google with 100 packets/second. I believe both these processes belong to Evolution. I'm running 12.04

I've had a slow network connection on only this computer and these processes are definitely the cause. Whenever my internet becomes unusable I find these processes have started up again. Manually killing them fixes it.